# Regular Expression to find words NOT in a list

Tags: regex, regex-negation

A friend is writing for children at *Level One* and *Level Two*. At level one, the only words allowed are  those in a list of 100 common words. At level two, it's a list of 200 common words. After writing, how can she locate words that break the rule?

It's easy enough to find words in a list, but how do we find words (and only words) that are NOT in a list?

Comment: If you have a dictionary of all words and remove those that are in the list of 100 or 200 words you are left with what you are asking for, though I suspect that's not what you are after. This does not look like a problem for which a regex will be of help.

Comment: This looks like a problem that can be solved by some type of look-up to the relevant word dictionary, and doing something like a join to see whether the words in the writing are contained in the list, with NULL values (as an example) entered when the word used is missing from the approved list. You can do this in a number of languages.

Comment: It's going to be really ugly with regex, but you could make an alternation within a negative lookahead. Something like: [`\b(?!(?:hello|world))\w+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/kl7bZq/1/)

Comment: I want to select words ... but not the words in my list. The hello world string doesn't select 'hello' or 'world', but nor does it select 'I'd' or 'that's' or 'she'd'. When I modify it attempting to select everything but a|an|the, it avoids not only 'a' but all words that *start* with a (and all words that start with 'the').

I do believe there's a regex solution, but that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

@bobby, I would suggest checking result of regex.  If its null then it means the word is not in the word list. Example :

words:

```
apple orange pear
```

regex:

```
(kiwi)
```

result should be empty array

One website that I find useful to test regex is https://regexr.com/.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't want just a test. I want to do something to the words that don't belong.